# how use "|" ,the pipe ,in gawk with cmd.exe

Tags: windows, command-line

```
gawk '{print $1|"sort"}' somfile
```

This will do in cygwin bash, but in cmd.exe, it failed.
My gawk's version info:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>gawk --version
```

GNU Awk 3.1.5

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps because in cmd.exe you have to use double-quotes (") not apostrophe (') to delimit parameters.

```
  gawk "{print $1|\"sort\"}" somefile
```

(untested)

Comment: Close ;). You need the outer double quotes to make `gawk` recognize the whole expression, but the inner single quotes must be double quotes as well, so they need to be escaped: `gawk "{print $1|\"sort\"}" somefile`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Thanks for the correction. I'll update the answer accordingly.